# Dragging elements WITHOUT jQuery

Tags: javascript

I am currently working on an online presentation software. For the sake of this question imagine it as powerpoint or keynote.
I want to be able to add elements to the slide and then drag them around (live), getting the new position, updating the database.
However I want to do this without any use of external libraries or frameworks, including jQuery.
Can anyone point me in a direction for my research? My current ideas to implement this are pretty messy. Especially the live-dragging is what's giving me headaches.

Thanks!

UPDATE!

the elements look something like this:

```
<div class="textelement" 
data-id="528fc9026803fa9d4b03e506" 
data-role="Textelement" 
style=" left: 50px; 
top: 50px; 
z-index: 0; 
width: 72px; 
height: 72px;">
    <div class="textnode">slide: 0 textelement: 0</div>
</div>
```

Comment: I'm just starting to learn web development and I already figured out that without jQuery, HTML is completely useless.

Comment: Can you use HTML5 for this presentation?  There is a native drag/drop feature.  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DragDrop/Drag_and_Drop

Comment: @HighCore you know that jQuery is a Javascript Framework?

Comment: @HighCore that's ridiculous. jQuery was written in JavaScript.

Comment: http://html5doctor.com/native-drag-and-drop/

Comment: @Carlangueitor yes, I know that. That doesn't change the fact that HTML sucks without jQuery / js frameworks in general. BTW, did you finally become a programmer and decided to come here? if so, welcome =)

Comment: @HighCore Oh my. please don't. Learn what HTML is, what javascript is, and then speak about jQuery. And no, HTML is not completely useless!

Comment: @LeMoisela except when compared to XAML.

Comment: @HighCore You are confused my friend, XAML is just an abstraction of HTML and is ultimately rendered into HTML.

Comment: @RobM of course that is completely wrong. You have no idea what [XAML](http://www.istartedsomething.com/20091124/razorfone-conceptual-windows7-wpf-multi-touch-retail/) is

Comment: @HighCore what if i told you that you can make everything that you can make with jQuery with only plain Javascript? Maybe you cant start using this frmaework: http://vanilla-js.com/

Comment: @HighCore Touche, I was thinking of HAML.

Comment: @Carlangueitor Everything you can make with jQuery you can make with plain js, that's true. It's also true that you could chop down a tree with a completely disassembled chainsaw, provided you have time and effort to throw away by assembling it yourself.

Comment: @HighCore how in the world is HTML useless? I just smell flame/troll, since you don't have any solid argument.

Comment: @razpeitia `when compared to XAML`. And yes, looks like there's not much one could do without Javascript / jQuery / other js Frameworks.

Comment: @HighCore it's because HTML it's not a programming language (unlike js). Your comparison it's just meaningless.

Comment: @razpeitia neither is XAML, but still it's N times more powerful than HTML. Mostly when it comes to DataBinding and interactivity.

Comment: @HighCore I do not wish to contribute to this flaming thread, but, as an interesting note, the vast majority of websites on the TOR ("DarkNet") are developed without any sort of Javascript/JS. Just HTML. This is to protect the user from any sort of scripting exploits or other malicious code that is possible through JS. They have managed to accomplish a great deal with just HTML.

Comment: @NathanGibson yeah, I'm pretty sure there is a lot of `rich`, `highly interactive` content in there... Please dude...

Comment: @HighCore Well, not sure how rich and highly interactive relate to the discussion. 

Your claim:
"looks like there's not much one could do without Javascript / jQuery / other js Frameworks"

My rebuttal:
"They have managed to accomplish a great deal with just HTML."

Comment: @Nathangibson except it's 2013 (almost 2014), not 1985. UI frameworks / languages / platforms that don't allow or make it too hard to implement `Rich`, `Highly Interactive` UIs are completely useless and deprecated. So is HTML without JS / jQuery / others. And, this may sound a little biased, but once you get used to XAML,  everything else feels like crappy dinosaur MS-DOS stuff from 50 years ago.

Comment: @HighCore I'm not disagreeing about the use of JS, jQuery, and XAML. I actually love all three. What I'm disagreeing with is your assertion that you can't do much without JS/jQuery. In fact, you can do a great deal with just HTML/css, and it could still be useful and rich (though admittedly not highly interactive). As an example, I gave you an entire network of websites that nearly all avoid JS. 

Your original argument was that HTML was useless without jQuery--you just had to revise it because of how absurd that was. It's still absurd even if you include JS in the argument.

Comment: @NathanGibson yeah, I always give absurd arguments and statements, I wouldn't be myself if I didn't. I still can't stop thinking how much I would love to see a XAML-based Web with every single line of crappy HTML or JS I type.

Comment: @HighCore Now that I can relate to :D

Answer (score 4, accepted):

While HTML5 does provide native drag and drop, this isn't what you asked for. Check out this simple tutorial to accomplish dragging in vanilla JS: http://luke.breuer.com/tutorial/javascript-drag-and-drop-tutorial.aspx

Answer (score 4):

There is great vanilla JS snippet available, but with one problem - when element start dragged on clickable element, it "clicks" on mouseup: see it on http://codepen.io/ekurtovic/pen/LVpvmX

```
<div class="draggable">
  <a href="#" onclick="alert('clicked');">Dont click me, just drag</a>
</div>
<script>
  // external js: draggabilly.pkgd.js
  var draggie = new Draggabilly('.draggable');
</script>
```

here is the "plugin": [draggabilly](http://draggabilly.desandro.com/)

And, here is my independent solution, working by :class: of the element:

```
(function (document) {
    // Enable ECMAScript 5 strict mode within this function:
    'use strict';

    // Obtain a node list of all elements that have class="draggable":
    var draggable = document.getElementsByClassName('draggable'),
        draggableCount = draggable.length, // cache the length
        i; // iterator placeholder

    // This function initializes the drag of an element where an
    // event ("mousedown") has occurred:
    function startDrag(evt) {
        that.preventDefault();

        // The element's position is based on its top left corner,
        // but the mouse coordinates are inside of it, so we need
        // to calculate the positioning difference:
        var diffX = evt.clientX - this.offsetLeft,
            diffY = evt.clientY - this.offsetTop,
            that = this; // "this" refers to the current element,
        // let's keep it in cache for later use.

        // moveAlong places the current element (referenced by "that")
        // according to the current cursor position:
        function moveAlong(evt) {
            evt.preventDefault();
            var left = parseInt(evt.clientX - diffX);
            var top = parseInt(evt.clientY - diffY);

            // check for screen boundaries
            if (top < 0) { top = 0; }
            if (left < 0) { left = 0; }
            if (top > window.innerHeight-1) 
                { top = window.innerHeight-1; }
            if (left > window.innerWidth-1) 
                { left = window.innerWidth-1; }

            // set new position
            that.style.left = left + 'px';
            that.style.top = top + 'px';
        }

        // stopDrag removes event listeners from the element,
        // thus stopping the drag:
        function stopDrag() {
            document.removeEventListener('mousemove', moveAlong);
            document.removeEventListener('mouseup', stopDrag);
        }

        document.addEventListener('mouseup', stopDrag);
        document.addEventListener('mousemove', moveAlong);
        return false;
    }

    // Now that all the variables and functions are created,
    // we can go on and make the elements draggable by assigning
    // a "startDrag" function to a "mousedown" event that occurs
    // on those elements:
    if (draggableCount > 0) for (i = 0; i < draggableCount; i += 1) {
        draggable[i].addEventListener('mousedown', startDrag);
    }

}(document));
```